# Extjs Cascaded combobox with autosuggestion

Tags: javascript, combobox, autocomplete, extjs4.2

I'm having two comboboxes, one for **Company** and other for **Employees**. I want to make the Employee ComboBox dependent on the Company Id i.e. should get populated as per the selected value in Employee ComboBox. Also, I want to enable autosuggestion in Employee ComboBox. Below is the code I've written :

```
{
  xtype:'combo',
  multiSelect : false,
  store :companyStore,
  afterLabelTextTpl:'<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>',
  editable:true,
  forceSelection:true,
  id:'companyCombo',
  fieldLabel:'Company Name',
  displayField : 'CompanyName',
  valueField : 'CompanyId',
  submitEmptyText :'false' ,
  width:350,
  mode: 'remote',
  queryParam: 'query',
  hideTrigger: true,   
  selectOnFocus:true,
  typeAhead : true
},
{
  xtype:'combo',
  multiSelect : false,
  store : companyEmployeeStore,
  afterLabelTextTpl:'<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>',
  editable:true,
  forceSelection:true,
  id:'companyEmployeeCombo',
  fieldLabel:'Employee Name',
  displayField : 'EmployeeName',
  valueField : 'EmployeeId',
  submitEmptyText :'false' ,
  width:350,
  mode: 'remote',
  queryParam: 'query',
  hideTrigger: true,   
  selectOnFocus:true,
  typeAhead : true
}


var companyStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields : ['CompanyId','CompanyName'],
    proxy : {
        url : 'getListOfCompanies',
        type : 'ajax'
    }
});

var companyEmployeeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields : ['EmployeeId','EmployeeName'],
    proxy : {
        url : 'getListOfEmployeesForCompany',
        type : 'ajax'
    }
});
```

As per my knowledge, this line

```
queryParam: 'query',
```

will pass the value of the field to my backend. But as per my requirement, I need both **CompanyId** from Company ComboBox (for filtering/ cascading effect) as well as the value I typed `enter code here`in the Employee ComboBox (for autosuggestion).

How can I achieve the same ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add **CompanyId** like extraParams to **companyEmployeeStore** in [beforequery](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-beforequery) handler.

```
Ext.getCmp('companyEmployeeCombo').on({
  beforequery: function (queryPlan) {
    Ext.apply(queryPlan.combo.store.getProxy().extraParams, {
        CompanyId: EmployeeId /*bind your value*/
    });
  }
})
```